# MeteorJS insert not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have removed the autopublish as well as the insecure. I also create a folder client and server and each folder I have init.js which contains the code for the client and code for the server.

In the **init.js client side** I have the code

```
Template.adminSetup.events({
    'submit #adminFormSetup': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var adminid = event.target.adminid.value;
        var adminUsername = event.target.adminUsername.value;
        var adminEmail = event.target.adminEmail.value;
        var fname = event.target.fname.value;
        var lname = event.target.lname.value;
        var gender = event.target.gender.value;
        var dateBirth = event.target.dateBirth.value;
        Meteor.call('insertAdminData',adminid,adminUsername,adminEmail,fname,lname,gender,dateBirth);
        console.log(adminid);
        console.log(adminUsername);
        console.log(adminEmail);
        console.log(fname);
        console.log(lname);
        console.log(gender);
        console.log(dateBirth);
        alert("Admin Account Successfully Created!")
        Router.go('/accountChecker');
    }
});

Meteor.subscribe('test');
```

The code above gets the value from the form, now inside my **init.js server side** I have:

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(){
   return Meteor.users.find()
   return AdminAccount.find()
});

Meteor.methods({

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    //Method that will insert the admin data to the database
    'insertAdminData': function(adminid,adminUsername,adminEmail,fname,lname,gender,dateBirth) {
        AdminAccount.insert({
            adminid: adminid,
            adminUsername: adminUsername,
            adminEmail: adminEmail,
            firstname: fname,
            lastname: lname,
            gender: gender,
            dateBirth: dateBirth
        });
        console.log("you clicked the right button");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
});
```

Which stores the data in the collection called AdminAccount. When inserting the data, there is no error or any sign of warning in the console but the data does not store in the AdminAccount collection. I am not sure where in the code is wrong. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Are your console logs returning info? You might be adding an event to the wrong template, it happens to me all the time

Comment: @AramilRey - I tried adding a console.log in the server side and it does not show up when I execute the event, the log should supposed to show up. The console logs in the client side show up the correct data from the form but inserting them seems an issue. The method "Meteor.call()" seems not working.

Comment: In the server side, I added a `console.log("success");` below the insert to see if the two codes are connected and yes they are connected since the log shows up. I wonder why it does not insert

Comment: Are you not getting an error on the server console either? Try adding a callback to the method: `Meteor.call('insertAdminData',adminid,adminUsername,adminEmail,fname,lname,gender,dateBirth, function(error, result){ if(error){console.log(error);} });`

Comment: I just added the code and execute the event and no error or any sign of warning. I just see the data logs and a message "successfully added" but when I check the collection `AdminAccount.find().fetch();` it only shows this "[ ]" which I believe it is empty

Comment: I tried adding the insert directly in the client side but it says in the console "insert failed"

Comment: In the server nothing is there, just the log saying "you are clicking the right button"

Comment: what is in your publish function? can you try adding `return AdminAccoun.find({})`

Comment: Like Sasikanth says, make sure you are subscribed to data if you are trying to access it on the client. Try your `AdminAccount.find().fetch();` on the server to see if you have documents there.

Comment: I have now added the `return AdminAccoun.find({})` and still not working. I have added the code to display the data count under AdminAccount and the result is 0

Comment: @AutumnLeonard - the result of `AdminAccount.find().fetch();` is "[ ]" I tried also using `AdminAccount.find().count()` and the result is 0

Comment: Please update the question to reflect your current code. Right now the publication is empty, so you will not get any data on the client.

Comment: @MasterAM - I have now updated the code

Comment: OH MY GOD, i just removed the Meteor.users.find() and everything shows up

Comment: It is working now but, is there a way to add the Meteor.users.find() back? I kinda need the two of them in the publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AdminAccount` collection is not being published:

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(){
   return Meteor.users.find()
   return AdminAccount.find()
});
```

The first `return` prevents the second one from ever being reached.

You want to return an array of cursors from that publication:

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(){
   return [Meteor.users.find(), AdminAccount.find()];
});
```

Comment: Brilliant yet simple explanation, amazing . . that sorted it out :) thank you so much . . :)